# how to get checkbox enable to work in ie9?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The following code does work in FF. I am trying to set the checkbox to enabled with the enable button. The enable checkbox does not work in IE 9?

```
        function enablebut() {
            $('#CheckBoxList1_0').removeAttr("disabled");

            $('#CheckBoxList1 span').removeAttr("disabled");

        }


        function disablebut() {
            $('#CheckBoxList1_0').attr("disabled", true);

            $('#CheckBoxList1 span').attr("disabled", true);

        }




    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button type="button" onclick="enablebut();">
        enable</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="disablebut();">
        disable</button>
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" Enabled='false' runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="een"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think with JQuery you can set attr to false like you do when setting true

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If it's jQuery 1.6 or newer you should be using `prop` here instead of `attr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant you use the same code

```
function enablebut() {
         $('#CheckBoxList1_0').attr("disabled", false);

        $('#CheckBoxList1 span').attr("disabled", false);


    }
```

just change the parameter to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that you are using a different Id to select the checkbox. Is there any specific reason?
Id of the checkbox is "CheckBoxList1", but you are trying to select the checkbox with Id "CheckBoxList1_0"